# Distinction between finite and infinite Taylor series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a slightly daft question concerning Taylor series.

Say if I want to approximate a function about a point $a$, and I am using a finite Taylor series of order $m$, then this series will be a "decent" approximation of my function **only** in a small neighborhood around $a$.

However, when we are approximating functions by infinite Taylor series (which have a certain ratio of convergence $R$), we still have to define a center $a$. What I am confused about, is whether in this case the function will be "decently" approximated  once again in a very small neighborhood around the center $a$ or in the whole interval, $|x-a|< R$? Is this what distinguishes the two series? Is the term approximation applicable here (for infinite series)? (Or is the function exactly equal in this interval).

Comment: Everywhere in your interval of converges Taylor series converges to original function.

Comment: There is no finite series, I mean you want to say *Taylor polynomial* instead of finite series.

Comment: @Msacroso [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28-1%29^%28n%2B1%29+z^n%2Fn+from+n%3D1+to+inf). But yes, I forgot about functions like $f(x) = e^{-1 / x^2}$ if $x\neq0$, else 0. But i was talking about analytic functions, tbh.